# Can't retrieve value from session

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, session

I want to pass session Id variable to SQLDataSource SelectParameter as:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [employees] WHERE ([username] = @username)"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employees] SET first_name = @first_name, middle_name = @middle_name, last_name = @last_name, father_name = @father_name, nic = @nic, age = @age, contact_no = @contact_no, gender = @gender, join_date = @join_date, qualification = @qualification, qualification_year = @qualification_year, univ_college = @univ_college, salary = @salary, experience = @experience, remarks = @remarks, status = @status, role = @role, bank_acct_no = @bank_acct_no, bank_name = @bank_name, blood_group = @blood_group WHERE username = @username">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="<%= Response.Write((string)Session['usernameId']) %>" Name="username" QueryStringField="username"
                        Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but get error, and can't retrieve session id. How to evaluate this:

```
DefaultValue="<%= Response.Write((string)Session['usernameId']) %>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `SessionParameter` instead of `QueryStringParameter`:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="username" SessionField="usernameId" DefaultValue="fixedValue" Type="String" />
```

Also, `DefaultValue` is a fixed value, and `Response.Write` inside a default value definition is non-sense. There is nothing to write to the HTML itself, you set the value of a server side control.

Comment: @badar: need more help?

Comment: I am using SessionParameter, but asp doesn't pick it. When I don't use <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="username" 
                            QueryStringField="username" Type="String" />. I get this error: Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

Comment: Mr. Patrick can you help here? Any tutorial on Web. I have tried but still in vein. I just want to pass session Id value dynamically to SelectParameter.

Comment: You should set the name of the parameter. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [employees] WHERE ([username] = @username)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employees] SET first_name = @first_name, middle_name = @middle_name, last_name = @last_name, father_name = @father_name, nic = @nic, age = @age, contact_no = @contact_no, gender = @gender, join_date = @join_date, qualification = @qualification, qualification_year = @qualification_year, univ_college = @univ_college, salary = @salary, experience = @experience, remarks = @remarks, status = @status, role = @role, bank_acct_no = @bank_acct_no, bank_name = @bank_name, blood_group = @blood_group WHERE username = @username">
            <SelectParameters>
               <asp:SessionParameter Name="SessionVar" SessionField="usernameId" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

or you can refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx